# Immigrant single entry visa in old passport

Tags: visas

I have received Canadian PR immigrant visa on June 11, 2018, my visa expiry is 10 June 2019  and passport Expiry is in 7 Aug 2019.
I plan to travel from Dhaka to Toronto, Canada in the coming march 2019. But, I came to know that one cannot travel during last 6 six months when your passport is about to expire.
Though it is an Immigrant visa (single entry) but also agent told me that airline will not allow me to on-board. That is why, already I collected new passport. Can anyone tell me, will it be an issue in canadian immigration as visa is in my old passport?

Thanks a lot in advance for your attention.

Comment: "But, I came to know that one cannot travel during last 6 six months when your passport is about to expire": where did you come by this information?  Some countries have rules like that for nonimmigrants, but Canada does not.  The rules for immigrants could be different, however.

Comment: I do not see any validity requirement for the passport, nor do I see anything that suggests that cancelling the passport containing the visa for a new passport application would affect the validity of the visa.  Do make sure the visa wasn't clipped, though, when the first passport was cancelled. If it was, you almost certainly need a new one.  My source is https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/regulations/sor-2002-227/index.html.  If your old passport wasn't cancelled, you're certainly fine.

Comment: A Canadian immigrant visa is not 'single entry'. Once you are admitted as a Permanent Resident you can enter Canada as many times as you like, with the appropriate documentation.